# I’m not grasping Bootstrap’s grid with two columns to one column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I’ve been looking at some articles but I’m not really grasping this concept.

Let’s say that I have a two column grid for medium and large devices. In the first column there is some text and in the second column is an image. When the browser is in small and x-small I would like the grid to be one column with the image on top of the text.

First off I’m not 100% sure I understand how to make the grid reduce from two column to one column with the same grid code and then even if it did, because the image is initially in the second column, wouldn’t it move to below the text in the first column?

So the only way I can think on how to handle this at the moment is to create two grids the way I would like to see them and then hide one or the other depending on the browser side. That just feels like double work to maintain two sections of the same page based on browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap `push` `pull` classes to reverse the column order on `md` and `lg` screens. On `sm` and `xs` widths the columns will stack in their natural order.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6"><img src=".."></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Nn6SKXwdH6

Comment: Since I didn't know about Push/Pull, I started researching that once you showed me here. I then came to this link which helps with understanding of column ordering. https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Comment: Here's the StackOverflow [docs on push pull](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/3330/grid-system/21719/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull#t=201703221435175090626) and a [complete guide to Bootstrap push pull](http://blog.codeply.com/2015/04/06/responsive-bootstrap-layouts/)

Comment: Can someone take a look at this plunker and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Reading the articles it seems as though I should design the mobile first which is what I did and it looks correct. However if you expand out the plunker to a large window it will split the image to the right with text to the left but the text is not pulled to the top so it's level with the image and it's also a little to far to the left. https://plnkr.co/edit/6Gm7Hvq3h6xINV7540LQ?p=preview